# SteamedResponse not working in lumen on other server

Tags: response, lumen, data-stream, symfony-http-foundation

I am using **Lumen** for a set of APIs.

using streamedresponse built in library of symphony.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

    protected function getFileResponseHeaders($filename)
{
    return [
        'Cache-Control'       => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
        'Content-type'        => 'text/csv; =utf-8',
        'charset'        => 'utf-8',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename='.$filename,
        'Expires'             => '0',
        'Pragma'              => 'public'
    ];
}
//'Content-Type: '
protected function streamFile($callback, $headers)
{
    $response = new StreamedResponse($callback, 200, $headers);
    $response->send();
}
```

I am using this approach in a scenario where I want to stream data in command line with chunks of 2000. I have bulk of data upto 7 millions rows to stream.

This whole thing is working completly fine on a server with following specs.

- php 7.3.27
- centos fedora 7
- apache 2.4.41
- mysql8

But I have other servers where this stream only list down first batch. Specs of other servers are identical as following:

- php 7.4
- centos 8
- apache 2.4.47
- mysql8

I want guidance to run this stream on all the servers. I have compared php.ini and every other thing that I can think of.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP ZTS** was missing from all the servers except the one where the streamed response was working.
Adding `php zts` on the server fixed the problem for me finally.